# php echo doesn't turn to ajax success

Tags: php, ajax, authentication

I have very simple question but I counld't handle it. When i enter username and password values and press login button, php doesn't return its value to ajax success. It opens webService.php page and echo result. Thanks for your help.

```
if($count==1){
    $_SESSION['UserName'] = $UserName;
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $Password;
    echo "true";
}
else  
    echo "false";
```

and my javascript code is;

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //javascript fonksiyonları


    $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#login").click(function() {


                var form_data = {

                    UserName: $("#UserName").val(),

                    Password: $("#Password").val(),


                    }

                    $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'webService.php',
                    data: form_data,
                    async:false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);}

                            });

                                                });



    });         


    </script>
```

I added "js/jquery-1.6.js"library
it just returns true in webservice.php page.

Comment: Show where you make the Javascript call...

Comment: So... you get an alert box with "false" in it???

Comment: Where/when are you calling ajax

Comment: Are you getting "false" as a result, or no result at all? Have you tried using an `error` handler besides `success`?

Comment: Yes, your problem is probably where you call your ajax function, so add the relevant html and script function(s)

Comment: @parker.sikand No he fails to call the PHP with ajax but instead goes to the PHP script itself...

Comment: Are you sure you're loading jquery.js?

Answer (score 0):

Check in FireBug or on server log what webService.php complete with status OK 200.
And you can add to ajax handler for error and check it.

May be your php script work with error and not returned with HTTP OK status - only in this case will run success handler.